# How do i test my CNN model with an image?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

## Intro/setup

I am new at programming, and i made my first CNN model from a tutorial. 
I have set my jupyter/tensorflow/keras up in C:\Users\labadmin

What i have understood is that i just have to put the path from labadmin in order to implement my data for testing and training.

Since i am not sure what is causing the error i have pasted the whole code and error, i think it is about the system not getting the data.

The folder with the Data set-up as following:

labadmin has a folder called **data** withing that there are two folders
**training** and **test**

Both cat images and dog images are shuffled in both folders. There are 10000 pictures in each folder, so there should be enough:

The tutorial teaches.
    1. How to create a model
    2. Define your labels 
    3. Create your training data
    4. Creating and building the layers
    5. Create your testing data
    6. (from what i understood) the last part of the code i have created is
    validating my model.

## This is the code

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from random import shuffle
    from tqdm import tqdm

    TRAIN_DIR = "data\\training"
    TEST_DIR = "data\\test"
    IMG_SIZE = 50

    LR = 1e-3

    MODEL_NAME = 'dogvscats-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2cov-basic1')

    def label_img(img):
        word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
        if word_label == 'cat': return [1,0]
        elif word_label == 'dog': return [0,1]

    def creat_train_data():
        training_data = []
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
            label = label_img(img)
            path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
            img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
            training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])
        shuffle(training_data)
        np.save('training.npy', training_data) #save file
        return training_data

    import tflearn
    from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
    from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
    from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression



    # Building convolutional convnet
    convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')
    # http://tflearn.org/layers/conv/
    # http://tflearn.org/activations/
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 2, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 2, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

    #OUTPUT layer
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')

    def process_test_data():
        testing_data = []
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
            path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR,img)
            img_num = img.split ('.')[0]  #ID of pic=img_num
            img = cv2.resize(cv2-imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),  (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
            testing_data.append([np.array(img), img_num])

        np.save('test_data.npy', testing_data)
        return testing_data

    train_data = creat_train_data()
    #if you already have train data:
    #train_data = np.load('train_data.npy')
    100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 21756/21756 [02:39<00:00, 136.07it/s]

    if os.path.exists('{}<.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):
        model.load(MODEL_NAME)
        print('model loaded!')

    train = train_data[:-500]
    test = train_data[:-500]

    X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape( -1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1) #feature set
    Y= [i[1] for i in test] #label

    test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape( -1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1) 
    test_y= [i[1] for i in test] 

    model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=5, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
        snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

    Training Step: 1664  | total loss: 9.55887 | time: 63.467s
    | Adam | epoch: 005 | loss: 9.55887 - acc: 0.5849 -- iter: 21248/21256
    Training Step: 1665  | total loss: 9.71830 | time: 74.722s
    | Adam | epoch: 005 | loss: 9.71830 - acc: 0.5779 | val_loss: 9.81653 - val_acc: 0.5737 -- iter: 21256/21256
    --
```

## Three Questions

I have three issues which i have tried to solve, but i have had no luck finding solutions:

### The first appears at: # Building convolutional convnet

```
    curses is not supported on this machine (please install/reinstall curses for an optimal experience)
    WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\labadmin\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\initializations.py:119: UniformUnitScaling.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use tf.initializers.variance_scaling instead with distribution=uniform to get equivalent behavior.
    WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\labadmin\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\objectives.py:66: calling reduce_sum (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
```

### The second appears at: print('model loaded!')

```
    if os.path.exists('{}<.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):
        model.load(MODEL_NAME)
        print('model loaded!')
```

Where the code does not print, does that mean that the data is not loaded?

### The third

Tutorial does not go through how can i test my model with a image. So how and what can i add to code that take the model (which also is being saved), and run an image from my folder with the given output being the classification?

Comment: I've update the answer. By the way, you should move the second question from answer to your main question by editing the main question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st: the warning messages are clear, follow it and the warning will be gone. But don't worry, you still can run your code normally if you don't.

2nd: Yes. If the `model load!` is not printed out, the model is not loaded, check your path to the model file.

3rd: To save model after training, use `model.save("PATH-TO-SAVE")`. Then you can load it by `model.load("PATH-TO-MODEL")`.

For prediction, use `model.predict({'input': X})`. See here http://tflearn.org/getting_started/#trainer-evaluator-predictor

### 2nd question

1. To save and load a model, use

```
# Save a model
model.save('path-to-folder-you-want-to-save/my_model.tflearn')
# Load a model
model.load('the-folder-where-your-model-located/my_model.tflearn')
```

remember that you should have the extension for the model file, which is `.tflearn`.

2. To predict, you need to load the image just like when you load it for training.

```
test_image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("path-of-the-image", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),  (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))

test_image = np.array(test_image).reshape( -1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

prediction = model.predict({'input': test_image })
```

Comment: Thak you for the quick respond!

Comment: Could you look at the 2. answer i have posted?